# Using same cookies from different source

Tags: authentication, go, cookies, session-cookies

I got a website with some useful data for me.
It has no open api.
What I want to do is to make a golang server, which will fetch this data once an hour and make some kind of analytics for me and then push it to my phone. But this data is only accessible for logged in users.
I made an app, where I open a login page, and then I grab cookies after I login and pass them to my server, so it can use them once on hour to make a requests to get those data.
But this seem to be not working.
What am I missing? Is it possible that this website checks for what ip adress was cookies made for?

Comment: How should we know without your code or the website in question?

Comment: And please show us the REST request and the response of your server

Comment: "Is it possible that this website checks for what ip adress was cookies made for?" Yes, of course that's possible. Along with a million other ways to bind a cookie to a particular device. I'm not sure what kind of help you expect from us. Obviously we can't tell you how to correctly interact with some unknown site. Your best bet is probably to let the server do the login, though.